# Excel - Plot average of two plots with inconsistent time (X) axis

Tags: excel, plot, average, axis

I have managed to plot two different data sets on the same axis however, I'm also looking to plotting another line showing their average.

The main problem is that both data sets have different X (time) values so it's not possible to add an average column at the end and plot that. (See the highlighted row 22 for example, corresponding Time values are different)

Is there any way I can plot an **average** of two plots on the same axis?

[image]

Comment: Use interpolation? I suspect that what Excel is literally plotting is a piecewise cubic interpolation (or something similar). Use that rather than the raw data.

Comment: Isn't there a native way of plotting average of the two?

Comment: Nothing is built-in as far as I know. It is easy enough (especially with VBA) to construct piecewise linear interpolations on a grid of points (e.g. every 0.01) and then plot the average of the interpolated values. If the data points are close together then this should be adequate. For something more sophisticated, maybe see this: https://blog.splitwise.com/2012/01/31/mystery-solved-the-secret-of-excel-curved-line-interpolation/

Comment: I was aware of the interpolation thing and have done that in MATLAB instead. I was just looking for a native way to do this in Excel. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: Perhaps some of the tools in the data analysis add-in (e.g. exponential smoothing) might help.

Answer (score 1):

One idea that *might* work is to place the values of both series, one above the other in two new columns, sort this new data according to time, smooth it, then plot the smoothed combined data. Alternatively, you could do the smoothing by simply plotting the new sorted series, adding a moving average trendline to it, then change the formatting of the new series so that it is no longer visible (but the trendline is). Something like this:

[image]

In the above picture, series 3 is the plot of the sorted aggregate data of series 1 and 2. If you change the formatting of series 3 so that there is no line, you get something like this:

[image]

For my relatively small mock data sets, the results are admittedly poor (it was based on just 25 data points in each series), but if you have a large amount of closely spaced data, and you play around with the moving average window size, you might get something acceptable. If not, you should probably just interpolate both datasets to obtain two consistent time series.